# Extended Euclidean Algorithm runs in time O(log(m)^2)

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

I'm interested in justification of the following line from the wikipedia article:

"This algorithm [extended euclidean algorithm] runs in time O(log(m)^2), assuming |a| < m, and is generally more efficient than exponentiation."
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Why is this so? Can anyone explain this to me? I understand completely the algorithm and all the maths, it is just that i do not see how to determine the complexity of such algorithms. Any more general hints?

Also, additionally: Is log meant to be the natural logarithm (ln) or the one with base 2?

Comment: "An algorithm is said to take logarithmic time if T(n) = O(log n). Due to the use of the binary numeral system by computers, the logarithm is frequently base 2 (that is, log2 n, sometimes written lg n). However, by the change of base equation for logarithms, loga n and logb n differ only by a constant multiplier, which in big-O notation is discarded; thus O(log n) is the standard notation for logarithmic time algorithms regardless of the base of the logarithm.", so log base doesn't matter it's really a constant base.

Answer (score -1):

The popular Introduction to algorithms book (http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) has got a whole chapter on proving algorithms complexity (however there's much more to the topic than in this book). You can read it if your generally interested in this matter.

You might also try to follow this paper's references: http://itee.uq.edu.au/~havas/cats03.pdf